# adb shows different battery capacity

Tags: battery, charging

My device is Coolpad Note 3 and it's 15 months old.
Recently, I've observed that the battery suddenly drops randomly to 20-30% and shuts down. When I plug it in for charging while it's powered off it shows that it's charging from 20-30%. If there is some charge left inside it then why won't it turn on?
And while charging it suddenly bumps up from 40-50% to 70-80%. Why does this happen? I don't think that the battery is failing because it's relatively new compared to my 2½ year old Redmi 1S (which is working perfectly).

Interestingly, `adb shell dumpsys batterystats | grep "Capacity:"` shows that my battery capacity is `1000` while the manufacturer mentioned that it is `3000 mah`. I was getting nearly 5 hours of screen on time before this happened. Did the manufacturer do something to the device by giving some update ? Recently many other users reported such battery drain issues. Malwarebytes scan shows that the `themes` and `ota updater` apps have `coolreaper` malware which can be used to directly install any apps.
Here's the complete output:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys batterystats | grep "Capacity:"
    Capacity: 1000, Computed drain: 0.1000, actual drain: 0.00000000
    Capacity: 1000, Computed drain: 0.1000, actual drain: 0.00000000
```

**Edit:**
I got the battery replaced from the service centre and it's working properly but `adb` is still showing the battery capacity as 1000 only.